# How can I switch back the SMB file service to SMB1?

Tags: macos, smb

I am using an Canon print workstation to send files to OS X. Unfortunately OS X El Capitan uses SMB3. It's no longer possible to send files scanned PDF files to OS X. How can I switch back to SMB1 for the OS X El Capitan SMB file service?

**Update:** The command isn't correct.

```
echo "[default]" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf; echo "smb_neg=smb1_only" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf
```

It sets the default network protocol to the slower but more reliable SMB 1 protocol. However I don’t want to connect to a SMB Windows file server. It’s the other way around. I am using the built-in OS X SMB file service (SMB3) and the printer connects to OS X.

Anyway, there aren’t many articles on how to force OS X SMB server to use SMB1. There is also a application [SMBUp](http://eduo.info/apps/smbup) which replaces Apple’s OS X native netbios and SMB services. You can find a detail tutorial here
http://www.tweaking4all.com/os-tips-and-tricks/macosx-tips-and-tricks/smbup-mac-os-x-smb-fix/

Solution: Finally I said goodbye to SMB and switched to FTP file protocol.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: Ahhh...  Give this a try.  It worked for Mavericks (SMB2) and should work here as well.  In Terminal issue:  `echo "[default]" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf; echo "smb_neg=smb1_only" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command sets the default network protocol to the slower but more reliable SMB 1 protocol. However I don’t want to connect to a SMB Windows file server. It’s the other way around. I am using the built-in OS X SMB file service (SMB3) and the printer connects to OS X.

Anyway, there aren’t many articles on how to force OS X SMB server to use SMB1. There is also a application [SMBUp](http://eduo.info/apps/smbup) which replaces Apple’s OS X native netbios and SMB services. You can find a detail tutorial here
http://www.tweaking4all.com/os-tips-and-tricks/macosx-tips-and-tricks/smbup-mac-os-x-smb-fix/

Solution: Finally I said goodbye to SMB and switched to FTP file protocol.

Comment: You should move this clarification to the question part as it's technically not an answer but a *clarification*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a few years back and I found the cleanest way was to install Samba (which still supports the older protocols) via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and use that instead of the version built by Apple.

I used [these instructions](http://blog.helloyama.com/post/77813860132/replacing-the-os-x-109-mavericks-smb-stack-with), which are for Mavericks but I think they should still work for newer versions of OS X.